# Replace percentages in transposed dataframe and print rows values as description text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A", "2000-01", "100", "10%"],
                   ["A", "2000-02", "200", "20%"],
                   ["B", "2000-01", "150", "15%"],
                   ["B", "2000-02", "150", "15%"],
                   ["C", "2000-01", "250", "25%"],
                   ["C", "2000-02", "350", "35%"],
                   ["D", "2000-01", "500", "50%"],
                   ["D", "2000-02", "300", "30%"],],
                  columns=["Label", "Date", "Count", "Percentage"])
```

I want to transpose it as

| Date | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000-01 | 10% | 15% | 25% | 50% |
| 2000-02 | 20% | 15% | 35% | 30% |

with

```
df_T= df.groupby(['Date','Label']).sum().transpose().stack(0).reset_index()
del df_T['level_0']
df_T[['A','B','C','D']] = df_T[['A','B','C','D']].apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=1)
```

I kinda got it.

But I'm failing with the percentages format. Thought this would work, but didn't (got an error):

```
 df_T['A','B','C','D'] = df_T['A','B','C','D'].map('{:,.2f}%'.format)
```

What am I missing here?

Very important also, I would like to print some output as:

*"In 2000-01, A = 10%,  B = 15%, C = 25%, D = 50%. \n
In 2000-02, A = 20%,  B = 15%, C = 35%, D = 30%. "*

to have a description text for a subsequent plot as an image (in case the image is not visible on the page and accessibility matters).

How's the best way to do it?

I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: Use `pivot`: `df.pivot('Date', 'Label', 'Percentage').reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very elegant and much easier! Still need the alttext, though!

Comment: You can loop through the dataframe returned from above code by rows with `.itertuples` or `.iterrows` and then format the each row into the text you needed.

Comment: `iterrows` worked just as needed. Thank you very much for the help @Psidom!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)